# Debug Quantlib Source code

Tags: c++, quantlib

I recently started to use Quantlib in Visual Studio. I have succesfully got Quantlib installed and working. I also managed to use Quantlib to price some products such as Swap and Swaption. The Swap prices match my own VBA calculator quite well (<0.5% difference). For Swaption prices, there are some difference (around 5%). So I want to check through all the intermediate results in Quantlib to see where does this 5% difference comes from. However, I cannot debug through the Quantlib source code in my project. I think this is because my project only include the pre-built Quantlib libary and boost libary, so I can see the header files only in my project. But, I cannot put break points in the header files to debug.

Although I can manually locate the source file in the Quantlib installation folder, it doesn't help with debugging. So my question is that is there any way I can step through the Quantlib source code in my project?

For example, I am currently interested in the detail calculation steps in **BlackSwaptionEngine**. I just need to set up the swaption and pricing engine, and use the Quantlib NPV function to get the result:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Exercise> europeanExercise(new EuropeanExercise(expiryDate));
Swaption testSwaption(swap, europeanExercise);

boost::shared_ptr<PricingEngine> swaptionEngine(new BlackSwaptionEngine(forwardingTermStructure, Vol));

testSwaption.setPricingEngine(swaptionEngine);

double res = testSwaption.NPV();
```

Yes, I can get result. But I also want to know the intermediate result inside the BlackSwaptionEngine. So step through the source code seems to be a good way to find this out. How can I include the Quantlib source code in my project to debug?

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: You'd need to obtain or build a debug version and link against that. There's no way (that I've ever seen or can possibly imagine) to combine a non-debug library with source files to 'add' debug ability. And btw, it's now called `std::shared_ptr`, having been Standardised in C++11, so you should use that version.

Comment: No, he shouldn't. The library still uses C++03 and `boost::shared_ptr`, because quite a few users still couldn't talk their IT departments into upgrading their compiler to a recent version. Banks are funny that way.

Comment: About debugging: what @underscore_d said. Where did you get the pre-built library? Could you build it yourself instead?

Comment: @LuigiBallabio Oh, I hadn't noticed the library received `boost` pointers as-is ( and then would've probably tripped over my unconscious, clearly false  assumption that smart pointers provided conversion to `raw *`! D: )

Comment: @underscore_d Thanks for your quick response. Is there any chance you can explain a little more on "link against debug version". I think I built the lib in debug mode. I follow this link (http://quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml) to set up the reference. Basically, just set up the path in VC++ Directory. I also disabled "Enable Just my Code" in debugging in visual studio. But, what I can see are still those header files.

Comment: @Ben10 When you said "my project only include the pre-built Quantlib libary", it sounded like you hadn't built it & had no way to. So that changes a lot! Which settings did you use to build? You might need to tell the compiler to retain debug symbols. & I think you'd have to put breakpoints in the library before compiling it, rather than trying to add them later in some other project that links to it. From the outside, you could probably add bps to func calls only. However, I'm not very advanced at debugging, nor have I used Visual Studio, so I think someone else should advise in more depth :)

Comment: @LuigiBallabio Thanks for your reply. I built the library by myself by following this [link](http://quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml). It works ok since my pricing function on swap does give me similar result as my own one. But, my swaption function doesn't match the quantlib result. So I want to step into the source code to see how the NPV is calculated by using the BlackSwaptionEngine. At the moment, I can only see the hpp file with a line of code 'calculate();' in an inline function inside **instrument.hpp** class, then NPV is found.

Comment: Visual Studio gives you the choice between a number of configurations when compiling the library. (I'm on a Mac right now so I can't make a screenshot for you, but there should be a drop-down menu in the toolbar.) You have probably compiled in the "Release" configuration. If you choose "Debug" instead, you should be able to debug the resulting library.

Comment: Actually, I _do_ have a screenshot for you, and it's at the [link](http://quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml) you used. If you scroll down, right before the "QuantLib Usage" section, there's a paragraph on building the debug version, with a screenshot of the configuration selection.

Comment: @LuigiBallabio Thanks for your advice. I think I built the library by setting it to all configurations. Let me start from the beginning and build a library in debug mode to see what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to debug into the Quantlib source code in the end. As Luigi suggested, we need to build Quantlib in **Debug** mode, and then link the library and directory as this link:

quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml

Then, we can step into the source code of Quantlib in the application project.